# SAS SQL where and having

Tags: sql, sas

```
select count(*) from tableA having product="abc";
select count(*) from tableA where product="abc";
```

why the outpur are different from the above statements as both are same?
Is it possible?

Comment: Use where for regular conditions, and having for aggregate function conditions.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` filters the records that go into the calculations. `HAVING` filters the result rows that are returned.

If you run your first query then SAS will warn you that it is remerging the results with the original data since you are referencing a non summary statistic variable in your HAVING clause.  Note that if no original records meet your HAVING clause then you get no observations in your result set.  But if ANY records meet your query then you get a separate observation for each observation that meets your HAVING clause, but count is for all observations since none were filtered.

Try this query.

```
proc sql ;
 select 'HAVING',count(*) from sashelp.class having name like 'A%'
 union all
 select 'WHERE',count(*) from sashelp.class where name like 'A%'
 ;
quit;
```

Then change `A%` to `Z%` and run it again.